# Read POST form data to populate a form - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've got a form that I'm doing validation on with **AngularJS**.  If it is valid then I'm posting to itself (php page) some HTTP Post data.  When the page loads back again I'd like to have AngularJS keep the fields that the user has posted.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you checked the answer ?

Comment: Please post the code that is being used by `ng-submit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by creating custom `service`.

**You can follow below steps :**

**Step 1 :** Create a service to store the form fields data on success response from the HTTP API call.

```
app.service('setGetData', function() {
    var data = '';
    getData: function() { return data; },
    setData: function(fieldData) { data = fieldData; }
});
```

**Step 2 :**

In the controller on success response from the `HTTP POST` call set the field data into the `setGetData` service.

```
setGetData.setData(fieldData);
```

Here, `fieldData` is the object of the form fields that the user has posted.

**Step 3 :** on click of back button. you can fetch the stored field data from the `setGetData` service.

```
  var res = setGetData.getData();
  console.log(res); // here res is the object of the fields data that you set earlier in the service.
```